# Getting list of values from particular column

Tags: jquery

I am learning jquery and currently playing with jsfiddle. To start with , i have watched basic vidoes on pluralsight and AppendTo.

If you take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/bmNKU/7/ , I am trying to get a list of values from a particular column( in this case a list of email Ids).

I have managed to get the loop but it shows values of all rows and cols...the final output i want is the list of all email ID in all rows from EmailID column. i.e, abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com etc...there can be any number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that creates a new unordered list using your markup. Should use td instead of th

http://jsfiddle.net/bmNKU/14/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* add a new ul to put emails into*/
    $('body').append( '<ul id="list"></ul>');    

    $("#btn").click(function() {
                             /* start an html string*/
        var html = ''; 
        /* loop over table*/
        $('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
            var email = $(this).find('th').eq(1).text();
            /* concatenate each new element to html string */
            html += '<li>' + email + '</li>';
        })

        /* add new html to DOM*/
        $('#list').html(html);

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It s great learning exp. I have one more question. for some selectors we put SPACE(e.g $(#mytable tr) )  and for some we put : eg ( $('tr:gt(0)'))  how do i know when to use SPACE and : ?

Comment: sorry, don't understand the space issue

Answer (score 1):

First, you should only use `th` on the header row (the one with 'ID', 'Email') and use `td` on the rows with data. Then you can select on `'#mytable td'`, which will skip the header columns. Second, if you use a class to label your columns, it will be much easier. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='ID'>1</td>
        <td class='Email'>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='ID'>2</td>
        <td class='Email'>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {
    $('#btn').click( function( ) {
        $('#mytable td.Email').each( function( ) {
            alert( $(this).html( ) );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. Both yours and @charlietfl examples helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up that markup a bit. Second, consider this version of your fiddle that finds all IDs and Emails and adds them to an array, which you can do with what you please (in this example, output to a div) on click of the button: http://jsfiddle.net/bmNKU/10/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html table should be adjusted. "th" is used to represent table column headers, not values. "td" should be used here instead.

Next, by specifying a class for each "td", you can easily refer to them via jquery.

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/bmNKU/11/)

​